# VBA: copy from one sheet into a master and check ID

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I am new in VBA and programming at all.

Following:

I have a "master sheet" where data is being stored and a "edit sheet" where data is being continuous entered.
When data is bein entered in edit sheet I want to copy the data when finished.

Everything works fine except the ID which is being given automatically in the edit sheet.

The columns are for example: ID, Name, Adress, ...

User enteres a new entry:

1, Marc, New York//

2, Pete, New York//

3, Sam, London

When he copy this data into the master sheet the ID is being copied normally.

Now when I enter again some data in the edit sheet the ID is again:
1, Jack, LA//
2, Andre, LA//

When I copy the data again in the master sheet it looks like:

1, Marc, New York//

2, Pete, New York//

3, Sam, London//

1, Jack, LA//

2, Andre, LA

Now I want an unique ID so the new entrys should be checked and edited to:

1, Marc, New York//

2, Pete, New York//

3, Sam, London//

4, Jack, LA//

5, Andre, LA

Comment: How is the ID currently being filled in? are you using a form to enter data or directly in the sheet?

Comment: If there is some vba code generating the ID "which is being given automatically", then this code needs to determine the greater of: the maximum value in the ID column on the Master Sheet and the maximum value in the ID column on the Edit sheet, then add one to whatever the result is.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: The ID is being given automatically:                                               Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Application.Max(Range("A:A")) + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let see it.

First, get the last ID from your **Master** sheet record.

And then, increase it one and save new data with that id in your **Edit** sheet.

After that, when you copy data from **Edit** sheet to **Master** sheet, you can't see duplicate ID. Try it.

Here, my example code for get last ID from **Master** sheet and **Edit** sheet.

```
'Get the last ID
lastID = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("A:A"),Sheets("EditSheet").Range("A:A"))
```

Comment: This needs to be modified to take account of the fact that you might be on the second item (or later) in the edit sheet, so it needs to be the greater of the maximum in MasterSheet and the maximum in EditSheet. Assuming that the ID columns contain only IDs, then MAX(Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("A:A"),Sheets("EditSheet").Range("A:A")) would be faster than looping through all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it now with reading the max ID from the MasterSheet and then replacing it in the EnterSheet before copying.

```
Set EnterSheet = ActiveSheet

lastID = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("A:A"))

i = 4
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    Cells(i, 1).Value = lastID + 1
    i = i + 1
    lastID = lastID + 1
Loop
```

and then the copy function...

Tnx to all!